# Disable autocorrection of (number) to -number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When I type `(number)` in Excel it autocorrects it to negative number, is there a way to disable functionality and just keep what I've typed (as text).

I know I could type `'` before, but I'd like to have a simpler solution. (Also I'm not interested in solutions using macros).

Comment: Format the cells as text? If it converts numbers to negative, the cell is formatted as `-General` or something like that.

Comment: If Excel thinks it's a number, it will store it as a negative number and then let you format the display using parentheses.  Once it's stored as a number, the original parentheses are lost, so retroactively changing it to text won't restore them.  It isn't really auto-correction, it's just Excel's recognizing the input as numeric.   Try pre-formatting the cells as text, as CodeCaster suggested.  That's not always foolproof, though.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster and @fixer1234. I hoped there is a song for that, but I'll look for another workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I've received now I can answer my question:

Converting `(abc)` to `-abc` is not an autocorrection in Excel, but it immediately recognize the entry as a number. So there is no easy way to change it, but there are workarounds:

- Select cells which will contain `(number)` and set their number formatting to Text
- Type `'` before the entry, that will force Excel to manage entry as text
- If possible, use different type of brackets, e.g. `{}` or `[]`